# Java - SPARQL query rewriting through parsing

Tags: java, parsing, jena

I am trying to use Jena or some other Java library to achieve some coding challenge (in this case a rewriting through post-order traversal). I am not asking a methodology to translate SPARQL to SQL query. I already have that.

I am currently trying to translate a given SPARQL query into an some other SQL query.

So far, I've used [Jena parser](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/algebra.html), that given a SPARQL query, returns an ARQ tree representation, that can be traversed in post-order. This is exactly what I want to do.

The only problem is that the [Walker](https://github.com/apache/jena/blob/master/jena-arq/src/main/java/org/apache/jena/sparql/algebra/walker/WalkerVisitor.java), just walks through the tree. What I would like to do, is something like this (suppose I am going through a MINUS) :

```
String visit(OpMinus minus){

    String l_res = minus.getLeft().visit();
    String r_res = minus.getRight().visit();

    /*

    ... do some stuff with the result ...

    */

    String res = l_res + "MINUS (" + r_res + ")";
    return res;
}
```

Jena's visitor however returns void, making this impossible. Is there another way of doing it, instead of copying the Walker and the Visitor code, in order to make it work the way I want ? Thank you.

I am not looking for a SPARQL-to-SQL direct translator, because I need to work with the tree elements.

Comment: A walker does not return anything, but `Transformer` and the `Transform` classes do.

Comment: Your question suggests a generalized translation, but that is not possible, because SPARQL and SQL have significant differences. Virtuoso performs such translations in different ways for different jobs. Translating "a given" (do you mean "any given" or "a specific"?) SPARQL query to "an equivalent" SQL query depends on the SQL schema(s), SQL dialects, SQL engines, and RDF ontology/ies in use, among other variables. So perhaps your question could be modified to include some mention of your target SQL backend(s), and more about your specific SPARQL query/ies?

Comment: @TallTed Yes, of course I am trying to translate only a fragment of sparql into some generic SQL dialect. This however was not the main purpose of the question. I am not trying to find a method to translate a given sparql query, but given this method I already have, I am trying to be able to do it via Jena or some other library without rewriting everything.

Comment: @AKSW This is an idea, I could investigate, even though it wouldn't be really a clean solution. Thank you though

Comment: So, your question isn't about SPARQL nor SQL nor translating between them, but about some specific Java and Jena (or other Java library) programming challenge... Please edit the title and the body to make this clearer! The larger context of your immediate question *is* good to include, but that context should not appear to be the main focus.

Comment: @TallTed I edited as you suggested. Thank you

Comment: @ValerioColitta afaik, there is no visitor that allows for defining a return type. So yes, you have to implement it by yourself. But it's trivial to be fair. Good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually solved the problem by implementing my own Walker (since anything I am looking for is implemented in Jena) that traverses the tree in post-order and returns Strings